# How does addition/subtraction of float numbers work in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I don't understand what is going on in the following lines of code:

```
>>> 123456789012345678. -123456789012345677.
0.0
```

Shouldn't the result be 1.0?

Thanks. Cheers :)

Comment: Duplicate of so many "float math is broken" questions. Perhaps SO should add a special hint to pop up when floats are mentioned in a new question (+ perhaps a few other heuristics to eliminate the worst false positives)...

Comment: Float math works the way **float** math works, not the way we expect float **math** to work.

Comment: Maybe downvoters should take into account a) the OP is a newcomer in his first SO question. b) the answer is not evident for a noob and in fact an answer got 5 upvotes c) neither is to relate the problem with other headers in SO

Comment: @delnan: Technically, it's not a duplicate.  Most newbie "float math is broken" questions are about the non-decimal base.  This one is about the limited precision.

Answer (score 7):

Floats only store 53 bits of information, so you are being affected by round-off.

Use integers instead:

```
>>> 123456789012345678 - 123456789012345677
1
```

Or use the Decimal module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('123456789012345678.0') - Decimal('123456789012345677.0')
Decimal('1.0')
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact representation of 123456789012345678 as a float:

```
>>> 123456789012345678.
1.2345678901234568e+17
                 ^ oops
```

Answer (score 3):

[Floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) are stored as 53 bits<sup>1</sup> of mantissa plus 11 bits of exponent, plus a sign bit.
[image]

Your numbers require more than 53 bits to represent, so the nearest actual representable floating point value is used.

Floating point numbers usually model real-world measurements or simulations of real-world systems. Few if any physical constants or measurements are known to anything even close to 52 bits of precision, so this normally works out OK.

---

<sup>1. The 53<sup>rd</sup> bit is a *hidden bit* but it isn't enough to help you:

$ dc

2 52^p

4503599627370496

2 53^p

9007199254740992

123456789012345678 <<<< your number is bigger, actually, it requires about 56 bits:

2o 2 53^1-p

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

123456789012345678p 

110110110100110110100101110100110001100001111001101001110</sup>

Comment: Effectively, it is a 53 bit mantissa but the leading 1 isn't stored.

Answer (score 1):

Float arithmetics has common issue of rounding problem.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dsc&id=/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)